# how to get records from multiple column search in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

below mysql query not getting one particular record  from multiple column search using php.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT entrydate,refno, ppt1,country,
                status,submission,collection,invoice 
        FROM vsentries 
        WHERE ctype LIKE '%$ctp%' 
        AND client LIKE '%$layout_select%' 
        OR refno LIKE '%$refno%' 
        OR firstname LIKE '%$pax2%' 
        OR ppt1 LIKE '%$ppts%' 
        OR  country LIKE '%$country%";
```

can anyone suggest how to fix it!

Comment: Mixing AND and OR ... Use brackets to ensure the correct application of these

Comment: ok big bro.........let me see..

Comment: thanks bro now the problem has been solved.......